# Tried to install app from Google but it said it can't because it's already there. It isn't

Tags: google-play-store

Tried to install app from Google but it said it can't because it's already there. It isn't. Google suggested I delete it but it isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

- Open your device's main Settings menu.
- Select Apps or Application manager (this may be different depending on * your device).
- Select Google Play Store from your list of apps.
- Touch Clear data.